# Trying to cause an Out of Memory Exception with Postman

Tags: java, testing, gradle, out-of-memory

I'm trying to test out a simple script that will kill and restart a service if it encounters an out of memory error.  The service itself does full CRUD operations, and calls the script in the JVM options defined in its start script.

In the start.sh script:

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Xmx512m" "-Dapp.name=app-service" "-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=./oom.sh" "-Dspring.profiles.active='"$1"'"'

exec nohup "$JAVACMD" $DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS -jar $CLASSPATH > stdout.out 2> stderr.err &
```

And in oom.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

kill %p;

echo "service out of memory"
sleep 5
echo "Restarting service"

./start.sh profileName
```

My biggest issue right now is actually testing the script by inducing an OOM error.  Theoretically, what will happen is that the oom.sh script will be called, killing and then restarting the service.  I've tried using Postman Runner to send 500 get all requests, with no luck.  Does anyone know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Would Java Service Wrapper work? It's designed to handle various scenarios where your app should be running, but for some reason isn't (including running out of memory). It's pretty battle-hardended, too. https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com

You may have specific reasons / requirements against using something like Wrapper, but it's worth a look if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

This produces an out of memory exception quickly:

```
String s = "x";
while (s.length() > 0) {
  s += s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of inducing an OutOfMemoryError with a simple program:
https://crunchify.com/how-to-generate-out-of-memory-oom-in-java-programatically/

The program consumes more memory with each loop.

As a comment points out, you can also just throw an OutOfMemoryError for testing purposes:

```
throw new java.lang.OutOfMemoryError();
```